# clearTimeout/setTimeout on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, settimeout, hammer.js, mobile-devices, cleartimeout

I have to make a button that has the following functions:

If you click on it, it should show some lines and hide them after 3 seconds, but if you click on the button before the 3 seconds are over the lines should hide as well.

I have written some code that is working perfectly on desktop browsers, but on mobile browsers it is not. Android devices seem to ignore my clearTimeout and on iphones it seems more like a "buttonPressed" event.

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jC32X/6/) so that you can see what i have written.

```
var timeout = null;
var buttonCallback = function() {
    if( timeout === null ) {
        log('show lines');
        timeout = setTimeout(buttonCallback, 3000);
    }
    else {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
        log('hide lines');
    }
}


var hammerElement = Hammer(document.getElementById('showLines'));

hammerElement.on("touch", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    buttonCallback();
});
```

Any idea how i can make this behaviour work for mobile browsers?

Comment: On my iPhone your fiddle works. But what problem do you exactly have, you just said "it does not work".

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I'd try using a newer version of Hammer.js if you can though. 1.1.3 is the latest version and your Fiddle is using 1.0.10. There could be a bug in how it is handling events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that on some mobile devices that I was testing (not all!) has sometimes send 2 tab events (double tab).

To fix that I have been added a delayTime and checked when the function got called last time.

```
var buttonCallback = function() {
    if( timeout === null ) {
        //for old slow andoid devices
        if ((new Date().getTime() - delayTime) < 2200) 
            return;
        delayTime = new Date().getTime();
        log('show lines');
        timeout = setTimeout(buttonCallback, 3000);
    }
    // for fast devices to prevent the double tab error
    else if ( (new Date().getTime() - delayTime) > 1200 ) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
        log('hide lines');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @wumm mentioned, it works in my iPhone5 iOS7 as well.
Another way you could try is this fiddle I setup for you: http://jsfiddle.net/thePav/jC32X/5

HTML

```
<button id="showLines">Show Lines</button>
```

JS

```
var timeout;
var flag = false;

  function buttonCallback() {
    $('#showLines').click(function(){
      if(flag == false){
        flag = true;
        //show lines here
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
          flag = false;
          //hide lines here
        }, 3000);
      }else{
        flag = false;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        //hide lines here
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    buttonCallback();
  });
```

Not sure what the issue with your code was but this is just another way to implement it.